# How do I generate a unique slug with TypeScript and mongoose?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

I searched many modules for this but it didn't work for TypeScript like mongoose-slug-generator and mongoose-slug-plugin

Comment: If it works in javascript, it will also work in typescript. You may not have typings though ...

Comment: can you give me an example

Comment: the docs provide examples on the usage ...

Comment: when I do for example this :
import * as slugGenerator from 'mongoose-slug-generator';
it gives me : 
 Try `npm i --save-dev @types/mongoose-slug-generator` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'mongoose-slug-generator';`

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to use mongoose-slug-generator, import or initialize the module like so:

```bash
// someModel.ts
...
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

// not import * as slugGenerator from 'mongoose-slug-generator' but
const  slug = require('mongoose-slug-generator')

mongoose.plugin(slug)
```

Since the aforementioned module does not presently support TS, `require` must be used instead of `import`. I used this method and found that it was effective for generating new documents, but not for editing/updating existing ones. I didn't go too far in setting up the solution using this module, and I hope that `mongoose-slug-generator` will continue to be updated to become a TS friendly module.

So far, I've found that utilizing the `mongoose.pre('save')` middleware in conjunction with the `slugify` module is the most efficient choice for the project I'm working on.

E.g.

```bash
// someModel.ts
import mongoose, { Schema, Document } from 'mongoose'
import slugify from 'slugify'

export interface IPost extends Document {
  id: string
  title: string
  slug: string
  ...
}

const PostSchema: Schema = new Schema<IPost>(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      unique: true,
      index: true,
    },
    slug: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
    },
    ...
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
    timestamps: true,
  }
)

PostSchema.pre<IPost>('save', async function (next) {
  const post = this as IPost

  if (!post.isModified('title')) return next()

  const slug = slugify(post.title, { lower: true, trim: true })

  post.slug = slug

  return next()
})

...

// someController.ts
...

const updatePost = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
     const { postId } = req.params

    const { title, ... } = req.body
      
    try {
       // const post = await Post.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, { new: true }) not working instead:

      let post = await Post.findById(postId)

      post!.title = title
     ...

    await post?.save()  
    
    return res.status(200).json(post)
    } catch (err) {
        if (err instanceof Error) {
            console.error(err.message)
       }
        
  }
```